# How to check if I have the correct drive installed for the correct video card

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon

I have a notebook Dell Inspiron i15-5567-D40B.

The descriptions of the hardware say that this notebook has an AMD Radeon R7 M445.

I think my system is not recognizing.

How to know if the system is recognizing and also if the correct driver is installed.

Typing `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Dusplay'` I have this:

[image]

It's seems that the driver installed is for Radeon R7 M260/M265, but my card is a R7 M445. I'm correct?

Comment: The driver is the same and is correct.

Comment: How the same? I didn't understand. Can you explain, please?

Comment: I mean `amdgpu` is the correct driver regardless of the card.

Comment: Yes, but my card is not a R7 M260/M265. Is a R7 M445.

Comment: Again, the driver is correct. Do you actually have a problem? If so better to ask about that problem, instead of just conjectures.